# class cast exception when getting instance of Application in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

i am developing an app with fragments.
i want to get a instance of my application in my fragment.

my code is

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    MyAppName _app = (MyAppName) getActivity().getApplication();  
    }
```

but i am getting class cast exception.

My log cat is

```
09-02 18:01:27.750: E/AndroidRuntime(19210): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
```

please help me out.

Comment: if you need the activty context `getActivity()` is enough.

Comment: @Raghunandan I want instance of my application which is extending application class.

Comment: You must have a application class in your project and map that to the application tag in your manifest . For ex in the application you should have :      `<application
        android:name="yourpackageName.MyAppName"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should have one application class with extends Application
and that name should be specify in  manifest  with application
        android:name="pkg_name.app_class_name"